# Coordinate systems in modelling balloon ascent dynamic

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems

I coded the dynamics of a latex balloon throught standard ODE integration, set in a 3-dimensional cartesian space (z = altitude, x = North direction, y = East direction).

z-cooordinate accelleration depends, as usual, on gravity, buoyancy and ascent drag. 
x and y-coordinates accelleration depends on winds and lateral drag.
Winds were simply modelled by a 3 columns look-up table with altitude-wind azimuth (angle from North)-wind speed: at each altitude layer, winds vector in that range were mapped onto x and y component of the ODE system.
No problem in going that far.

After that, I wanted to obtain the geodetic latitude-longitude-altitude ballon path relative to Earth (WSG84). Thinking to the coordinate system where I integrated the dynamic, I decided it was considerable as a local cartesian NED system, with origin set at balloon lanch point ('z' has opposite direction, but it doesn't change the concepts). Given that, I simply transformed the (x,y,z) from this NED system (never changed along the integration) into the geodetic system (WSG84 ellipsoid).

Now, considering for example a balloon that reach a certain fixed floating altitude (z constant after a certain integration time) and after that moves only by winds (so in the x,y directions), when you convert the dynamic into geodetic, you ends with an altitude that is increasing (while 'z' doesn't move) !

Actually, if you consider the x,y 'surface' as a plane (tangent to the NED system origin), it is logical that, when the ballon displacement gets bigger, the (x,y) plane gets further and further from the Earth surface. It follows then that geodetical altitude increases as the integration 'z' coordinates remains fixed.
If this is the concept, you are using a FIXED 'flat Earth' system, and so when you move 'too much' from the origin, the 'flat Earth' approximation fails.

If the reasoning is correct, how to deal with this issue ? Should I have to 'update' the local system in order to take the Earth curvature into account ?
And, if this is the case, how to do ?

But I propose you another point of view. The (x,y) balloon displacement depends (pratically) only on winds vector (with 'winds' I mean, from now on, the azimuth and speed at a certain altitude). Winds blows in an Earth PARALLEL fashion, so their components are naturally given (forecast or actual) for a curved surface.
So, when you apply the x and y winds components to you ODE integration, you are implicitly considering a vector that stays, at any point, tangent to the Earth surface. 
Given that, the ODE NED system is already geodetically curved, and so the 'z' component is really the ballon altitude from Earth (so no need to translate coordinates ... it would be wrong actually).

Can you help me understand how things are ?

Thanks

Maurizio

Comment: I find your question unclear. It is full of acronyms which only technophiles will be aware of. And it does not provide a clear statement of the problem.

Comment: OK, I will try to clarify. My question is: in which coordinate system/s do you solve the dynamic equation of a high altitude ballon (so a point object subject only to gravity, buoyancy and winds force with no thrust) in order to have its path in a geodetic coordinates ? Newtonian force equations are normally set up in a cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all of these sorts of questions is always "it depends."  The best answer varies based on the sorts of ranges you are looking at.

Clearly, if you are traveling a quarter of the way around the globe by balloon, you will not be able to use an NED coordinate system fixed at the launch point if you want the winds to be in the xy plane.  It's trivial to see that that would cause winds to drive you right into the ground, which is not what you want.  So right away, we can see that using a fixed NED will not work for defining the motion of the winds.

We can also see that it's not very effective for handling the paths you take.  If you travel along the equator a quarter-earth circumference, take a right turn to head to the north pole, then take a right turn at the north pole you are heading home.  You cannot model this unless you actually account for the curvature of the earth.

If you want to handle these cases (and Coriolis effects), the best way to do this is to integrate in ECEF or ECI.  Which one you want to use depends on the nature of your simulation, but it looks like ECEF is the "right" choice.  This means your equations of motion may have to include Coriolis explicitly (unless you can prove it doesn't really matter for your balloons), but it's convenient because points on the ground have 0 velocity.

Finally, we have the wind forces.  As you have  defined the winds, you are using a local NED frame.  Your wording almost uses it directly!  You'll want a local NED frame, updated at each timestep, and then you can use that to determine a xy wind force and a z force which tries to keep the altitude constant (buoyancy forces).